# Angular Universal Build error "missing script: build:ssr"

Tags: angular, universal

While adding Angular Universal to my project.

- I used the command line to execute the following:

  *npm install --save @angular/platform-server @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader ts-loader webpack-cli*

- Then I did the following command:

  *npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr*

I get this error:
**missing script: build:ssr**

Any ideas?

Comment: look in package.json it's the scripts section... do you see anything named build:ssr

Comment: I do not see anything named 'build:ssr"

Comment: ... and _that_ is why npm run build:ssr fails ... no such script, perhaps the script you are looking for is named something else (the keys of the scripts object are the only valid choices)

Comment: I've discovered that my project version was lower than the installed version of Universal. The two are out of sync.